# C# - Field values of an array picking up values of a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I'm training C# on a simple card game. I have methods that shuffle and deals the cards. I have a random deck that is well generated.
Is it possible to set an array for the player1 cards, picking up the first ten values of the array.
Here is a part of my code :

```
currentCard = 0;
    public Card DealCard()
    {
        if (currentCard < deck.Length)
            return deck[currentCard++];
        else
            return null;
    }
```

I want to pick up for example ten first values of

```
deck[currentCard++]
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks for your help !

Comment: What do you mean by "pick up"?

Comment: Well thank you guys for downvotes but it's not what I'm looking for, post is solved thanks

Comment: Downvotes can indicate lack of *demonstrated* research (i.e. in this particular case there are hundreds questions about slicing and dicing arrays in all possible ways) as well as clarity of the question (which this post somewhat lacking as it is not clear what exactly you don't understand - i.e. suggested `.Take(10)` answer *should* be over your head based on this question, but somehow it is very clear for you as you've accepted that answer).

Comment: Side note: please check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+fluff discussions before adding "thanks" to your next post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to pull the first 10 enties into another array? Something like;

```
var player1Cards = deck.Take(10);
```

or

```
List<int> player1Cards = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    player1Cards.Add(deck[i]);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you sir !